# correct use of scala Map keyset

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am fussing about how to derive a key from a Scala Map. 
The Map in question is simple:

The following function to derive a key from a Scala Map is here under:

```
def extractKey(myMap: Map[String, String]): String {
     //process myMap
      myMap = Map("SSN" -> "1")


      //return "SSN"
}

val myMap = Map("Visa Number" "10")
```

How do I extract the string Visa Number from it?

Okay, I tried this much so far:
myMap.keySet and I derived a Set out of it as: `scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set("Visa Number")`

I am a little confused about to proceed.

I tried the following:
myMap.keys
this returned a Iterable[String] = Set("Visa Number")

I also tried the following:

```
myMap.keysIterator that returned an Iterator[String]
```

So, what is the best way to derive a key out of the Map myMap

Now, what if I had a longer Map as:

```
myMapLonger = Map("SSN" -> "10", "AMEX" -> 11)
```

then how would i capture the keys and put them into a List?

thanks

Comment: I cannot get what exactly you want. Is'nt `myMapLonger.keySet.toList` or `myMapLonger.keysIterator.toList` sufficient ?

Comment: Describe the input and return types of the function you're looking for

Comment: I will add more context around the question. @ymonad..what i want is to simply extract the key from the Map as a String or as a List

Comment: @Daenyth i will update the question

Comment: @ymonad, I think myMapLonger.keysIterator.toList is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

```
 Map("SSN" -> "10", "AMEX" -> 11).keys.toSeq
```

or

```
 Map("SSN" -> "10", "AMEX" -> 11).toSeq.map(_._1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach invloves applying `unzip` on the given `Map`,

```
val (keys,values) = Map("SSN" -> "10", "AMEX" -> 11).unzip
```

which delivers a duple of lists, the first entry with the keys, the second with the values

```
keys: List(SSN, AMEX)
values: List(10, 11))
```